# How to get apt-get "Configuration Item" list?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management, 22.04

I want to get them all, which I can't from the `man apt-get` and `man apt.conf` commands, not even looking for them online.

In the manual, for example there is no `APT::Get::Clean` and putting a bogus option in the command `apt-get`, then:

```
sudo apt-get -o APT::Get::Swearword=true dist-upgrade
```

the command is executed correctly, no error appears and the exit code is equal to 0, so even attempts are not able to verify if an option exists or not.
How do I get the full list of existing options?

Comment: A Google search gives me this which I think is what you are asking https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Comment: not sure I got your question correctly, but may be the `apt-config dump` is what you are looking for?

Comment: `apt-config dump` only lists "active" configuration options, not all existing options that are not configured. I would imagine some kind of APT reference manual could include all available options - or maybe only the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `man apt.conf`:

> /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz is a configuration file showing example values for all possible options.

Sure enough, that example file is full of rare and exciting apt options! The file is named `configure-index` and is indeed the intended *reference* (complete list) of apt configuration options.

- The manpage is slightly in error -- it's a normal file, not gzipped file anymore. For any community member interested in learning how to file their first bug and create a patch, it's a great papercut to start upon.

So take a look at `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index` (included with the `apt` package) for the option reference.

Comment: That was rather solid detective work! 

Comment: Unfortunately none of the available options take effect (the effect of `apt-get clean`), if nothing else is the list of all available options. Congratulations for the answer.

Comment: There is no `clean` config option - see my answer.

Comment: Erasing the entire package cache is only necessary when troubleshooting and repairing specific problems (or freeing a small amount of disk space). I cannot envision a workflow where doing so as a *configuration option* would be helpful to anybody. As it is, `clean` is already terribly overused and abused.

Comment: Wow, this is another one for my "references" file.

Answer (score 1):

The file is also located in the [APT GitHub repository](https://github.com/Debian/apt), under [`apt / doc / examples / configure-index`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/main/doc/examples/configure-index)

Please note that under the "Get" section (found in line 62-128), there is no `clean` option.

So `clean` is only a *cli command*, not a *configuration option* (which is also evident from the `apt` manpage).

Comment: Ok, thank you. :-)